# Windows VPN Server software that supports bandwidth caps

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy, bandwidth-control

I am looking for a VPN server like OpenVPN that supports bandwidth caps for users. I posted an original question which in which I asked for a VPN server that supported bandwidth throttling - which is incorrect and I am sorry for this. What I am actually asking for is a VPN server that supports per-user bandwidth caps.

By finding Windows VPN server software that does this, I can provide a VPN service to my customers with a 1GB cap for free users. Users would be able to use the VPN up until their bandwidth cap, then it would cut off unless they upgraded their package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this product [Bandwidth Splitter](http://www.bsplitter.com/), which is an extension for ISA and Forefront.

> Setting up quotas for the maximum allowable Internet traffic use (in megabytes) for a set period of time (a day, a week or a month) for individual users and hosts, as well as groups of users and hosts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SoftEther](https://www.softether.org), which is open source and is extremely configurable. It might not have an out of the box option to cap traffic, but you can control it through its API.